# One less reputation after deleting my comment/answer

Tags: support

I have answered a question when my reputation was **339**. The answer got 3 downvotes. That makes my reputation 332 which should have been 333. Then I have deleted my post. After that the reputation again becomes 338

So in this case the reputation is having one point less than the normal (i.e. 339). Also I have checked in my account about downvotes, but I didn't get any clarification about this one point/reputation.

Any explanation on this situation ? Is it a bug or expected behaviour ?

Comment: Are you certain it was 339? I see -6 (3 downvotes) then +6 (3 removed downvotes) in your rep history http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/32560/kedar?tab=reputation

Comment: Have you downvoted any answers recently? Those count for -1 rep. That should show in your reputation feed too.

Comment: @BenBrocka : Yeah I am certain and sure. The reputation was 339 only.

Comment: @JonW : Yes, I have downvoted one answer, but I have downvoted many answers in the past. Still I had my reputation same and without any difference. Also that is not shown in my reputation feed as well.

Comment: There is a checkbox at the bottom of the screen on [your reputation page](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/32560/kedar?tab=reputation) called 'show removed posts'. Does ticking that make any difference to the list activity shown on your reputation feed?